# CC.Net Access Denied Error

Tags: iis-7, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have CruiseControl.Net setup as my continuous integration environment. I've been working on adding a Visual Studio 2008 Web Deployment Project to my solution but I'm getting a weird "access denied" error and I can't figure out why.

I have CC.Net running under its own account on my server which is a member of the administrators group, so the CC.Net service should have access to everything it needs. The problem is when I trigger a build from the web interface the build fails with the error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(667,5):
>   error : Access is denied.

The particular task on that line is the "`CreateVirtualDirectory`" task to create an IIS virtual directory for my asp.net application.

What's weird is if I open a command prompt on my build server running as the exact same user account the CruiseControl service is running as and run my build script everything builds successfully - including the creation of the IIS virtual directory. It's only when a build is initiated through the web interface that it fails.

I don't understand what the difference is between the two since presumably they are both running as the same user with the same privileges.

Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I have a similar issue with a unit test running on CCNet that creates a file in the CCNet user's temp directory.  It must have something to do with the context CCNet is running under, maybe a .NET security settings issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the virtual folder it is trying to create already exists?  Another thought - when you run from a command line, it is possible you have different environment variables or drive mappings that CC.Net wouldn't have?